# files not recognised BUT in same folder

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor

I have three files in my templates folder wheree there is also my main.html file. However when I load the html file I get a 404 error for these 3 files. This is how I've included them in the head of the html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="date.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="daterangepicker.css" />
```

They are all located in a templates folder in the same folder as my main.html.

Why aren't they being recognised?

Thanks

Comment: If you open a new browser tab and http:// directly to one of the files, what do you get?

Comment: Are you reading `main.html` from another file (you mention it is in a 'template' directory) and and outputting the result?

Comment: [W 121203 22:01:04 web:1462] 404 GET /date.js (127.0.0.1) 0.38ms
[W 121203 22:01:04 web:1462] 404 GET /daterangepicker.js (127.0.0.1) 0.31ms
[W 121203 22:01:04 web:1462] 404 GET /daterangepicker.css (127.0.0.1) 0.18ms

Comment: The above is the message I get in the server log

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey I have a base file which main.html inherits from. The script tags are located in the base html file.

Comment: The base.html file has links to other source eg. <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> and they work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your local paths are not resolving correctly.  Without seeing your directory structure I can't say for sure exactly where things are going wrong -- I'm a little confused as to where `main.html` and `base.html` are residing.

If `main.html` is the file being loaded in the browser, your `script` sources should be based off that directory.  If your template directory (we'll call it 'templates') is a child of the directory where `main.html` resides, you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/date.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="templates/daterangepicker.css" />
```

Alternatively, you could just resolved your entire URL to the appropriate path:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.myurl.com/templates/date.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks....main and base.html are all residing in the templates folder along with the .js and .css files. I resolved it by your alternative suggestion.